# access from another device in a LAN network to a web application published in IIS 10, API NET CORE 2.1

Tags: api, iis, .net-core, publish, shared-hosting

Currently I have a web application api with vue js published in IIS 10, I access from the same pc with the site: www.ollitarustica.com, previously change the config of the hosts file: 127.0.0.1 www.ollitarustica.com, likewise change the base URL of axios to: www.ollitarustica.com, everything is fine accessing from the same pc, but now I have the need for other devices (pc, tablet, cell phones) connected to the same LAN to access the web application published in IISS, until now and made some unsuccessful attempts and my lack of experience makes it very difficult, the following is the current configuration of the published site:

Configuracion de IIS:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Startup.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddDbContext<DbContextSistema>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Conexion")));

            services.AddCors(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("Todos",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("*").WithHeaders("*").WithMethods("*"));
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };
            });
        services.AddMvc();
    }



public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors("Todos");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
```

appsettings.json

```js
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    //"Conexion": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=dbsistema;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    "Conexion": "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=dbsistema;user id=sa;password=jucardi7;persist security info=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",




"Jwt": {
    "Key": "Clave Personalizada",
    "Issuer": "http://localhost:63038"
  }
```

Comment: Instead of faking DNS via modifying hosts files, please now go to the DNS server used in your environment and set up the necessary record for that domain name, so all machines can resolve it to the actual IP address of that IIS box. Talk to your network administrators if you don't know much about DNS setup.

Comment: thank you for your comment, this configuration necessarily I have to do myself, for that reason I asked for help to guide me, investigate what you tell me

Answer (score 0):

Since the hosts file is only worked on your localmachine, the domain will not be mapped to the IP address when you use the domain on another machine.

If you want to let the domain map to your IIS server IP address, you should create a DNS server and add the IP address record.

More details about how to create a DNS server and add domain record, I suggest you could refer to below article:

https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-a-dns-server-on-windows-server-2012